# Creating a Delayed Response in a Python 2 HTTP Server

Tags: python, http, testing, server

I'm creating a very simple HTTP server in python 2 for testing.

I would like to randomly delay by a fixed amount the reply to a GET request without closing the connection to the server or shutting down the server first.

Here is the current code I would like to modify:

```
# Only runs under Python 2

import BaseHTTPServer
import time
from datetime import datetime

class SimpleRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print "incoming request: " + self.path
        self.wfile.write('HTTP-1.0 200 Okay\r\n\r\n')
        self.wfile.write(modes(self.path))

def run(server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer,
    handler_class = SimpleRequestHandler):
    server_address = ('', 80)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()

def modes(argument):
    # returns value based on time of day to simulate data
    curr_time = datetime.now()
    seconds = int(curr_time.strftime('%S'))

    if seconds < 20:
        return "reply1"
    elif seconds >= 20 and seconds < 40:
        return "reply2"
    else:
        return "reply3"

run ( )
```

The delay would be be added every, say, 3rd or 4th time a GET is received but when the delay times out, a properly formed response would be sent.

Thanks.

Comment: are you asking, how can you cause python code to stop and not do anything for a period? `import time` `time.sleep(1)` Have you tried something and it's not working?

Comment: @Macattack Thanks for the reply. My first attempt was to add a `time.sleep()` line before one of the `return` lines in the set of if-elif statement's. However that would send the `HTTP-1.0 200 Okay` part of the reply, then pause and then send the `replyX` text. Was looking to make the entire reply pause and then be sent. I wound up brute forcing it by commenting out the first `self.write...` in `do_GET()` and moving the entire reply down into the `return` statements of `modes()`, preceded by a `time.sleep()` statement.

Comment: you could restructure `do_GET()` -         `result = modes(self.path)` `self.wfile.write('HTTP-1.0 200 Okay\r\n\r\n')` `self.wfile.write(result)` so that the sleep would happen before the 200 ok gets returned